# FastAPI dependencies (yield): how to call them manually?

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

FastAPI uses Depends() to inject variables either returned or yielded. Eg, [FastAPI/SQL](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/?h=sqlalchemy#main-fastapi-app):

```py
# Dependency
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
...
def create_user(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
...
```

If I wanted to use that `get_db()` somewhere else (outside a FastAPI route), how would I do that? I know it's Python core knowledge, but I can't seem to figure it out. My initial thought was `db = yield from get_db()`, but I can't call `yield from` in async functions (and don't know if it would work besides). Then I tried:

```
with get_db() as db:
   pass
```

Which fails as the original `get_db()` isn't wrapped as a `@contextmanager`. (Note, I don't want to decorate this - I'm using `get_db` as an example, I need to work with more complicated dependencies). Finally, I tried `db = next(get_db())` - which works, but I don't think that's the correct solution. When/how will `finally` be invoked - when my method returns? And in some other dependencies, there's post-yield code that needs to execute; would I need to call `next()` again to ensure that code executes? Seems like `next()` isn't the right way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18):

You can use `contextmanager` not as a decorator but as a function returning context manager:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

# Dependency
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


# synchronously
with contextmanager(get_db)() as session:  # execute until yield. Session is yielded value
    pass
# execute finally on exit from with
```

But keep in mind that the code will execute synchronously. If you want to execute it in a thread, then you can use the FastAPI tools:

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import contextmanager

from fastapi.concurrency import contextmanager_in_threadpool


async def some_coro():
    async with contextmanager_in_threadpool(contextmanager(get_db)()) as session:
        pass
```

Comment: Oi, I'd never have figured that out - glad I asked! Thanks

Comment: Why don't we use context manager as a decorator for get_db function and then use `with get_db() as session`

Comment: What if the `get_db` is async as well?