# How to use dependency injection with simple functions in Fast API?

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a simple function in Fast API app that gets called by a cron, something like this (note that this is not a get or post Fast API method but a simple function):

```
def read_user(user_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_user = crud.get_user(db, user_id=user_id)
```

where `get_db` is:

```
from database import SessionLocal

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

And `database.py` is:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "://url-to-db"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

Since crud method takes db (object of `SessionLocal` yielded by `get_db`) as a param, how do I use it as a dependency injection with my function just like we use in `GET` or `POST` as shown in code `read_user` method above.

Comment: In that case you should call `get_db` directly; the main point about using `Depends` is that you can have a hierarchy of dependencies resolved dynamically based on the request. See https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1105

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558958/fastapi-dependencies-yield-how-to-call-them-manually